# angular rxjs subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription

i am declaring a subscription in Angular like this:

```js
counterSubscription: Subscription
```

and it is giving me this error:

> Property 'counterSubscription' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

So what could be the initial value of a `Subscription` please?

Comment: `undefined`? Or `null`?

Comment: put a semicolon in the end. it should give a error.

Comment: `counterSubscription!: Subscription;` you can use this and initialize subscription in ngOnInit(). I would recommend to use `counterSubscription = new Subscription();` directly instead of initialize it in ngOnInit(). This can reduce your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are initializing your subscription in an angular lifecycle hook, like `ngOnInit`, you can use the [`Definite Assignment Assertion Operator`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) `!` to inform TypeScript that the variable will be initialized.

```
counterSubscription!: Subscription;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `strictPropertyInitialization: false` rule to your `tsconfig.json` to disable this behaviour.